# Why I'm getting exception: InvalidOperationException?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, ado.net

The Exception is on the code
The code is

```
string cs=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Sam"].ConnectionString;
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tblProduct", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    GridView1.DataSource = rdr;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

So I have a one web-Config file.so I am connect with it.
The code inside a web config is

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name ="Sam"
    connectionString=" data source=.\\SQLExpress; database=sample; Integrated Security=true " />
</connectionStrings>
```

After Compiling it there is no error but when I debug it, at the run time I got

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code.
>   Additional information: Instance failure.

Why I am getting such error

Comment: At which line are you getting this error ?

Comment: Do you have a complete exception, incl. the stacktrace?

Comment: On this line     con.Open();

Comment: I'm not so sure those spaces in the connection string are allowed, clean it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an error when you try to open a connection to the database.
you need to modify your connection string.
Try to replace the double-slash by only one. Also try to avoid the space inside your connection string.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name ="Sam"
    connectionString="data source=.\SQLExpress;database=sample;Integrated Security=true"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: OK please mark it as answer, and plz give me favor with an upvote